# A simple program to display a rolling ball

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var canvas_variable;
var init_x = 200;
var init_y = 300;
var x_move = 1;
function initialize_canvas()
{setInterval(draw_ball, 10);
 canvas_variable = bouncing_ball_canvas.getContext('2d');
  }
  function draw_ball()
   {
   canvas_variable.clearRect(0,0, 1000, 500);
   canvas_variable.beginPath();
   canvas_variable.fillStyle="#FF0000";
   canvas_variable.arc(init_x, init_y, 50, 0+init_x/50, Math.PI*2+init_x/50, true);
   canvas_variable.lineTo(init_x, init_y);
   canvas_variable.stroke();
   if( init_x<0 || init_x>1000) x_move = -x_move;
   init_x += x_move;
   }
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <canvas id="bouncing_ball_canvas" width="1000" height="500">
  </canvas>
  <body onLoad="initialize_canvas();">
  </body>
  </html>
```

This is a program of a rolling ball. The function draw_ball is called after every 10 milliseconds.The ball blinks during its motion. What is the solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to declare the variable bouncing_ball_canvas

Try adding:

```
bouncing_ball_canvas = document.getElementById("bouncing_ball_canvas");
```

before you declare canvas_variable.

**EDIT:**

The problem lies in the line:

```
canvas_variable.arc(init_x, init_y, 50, 0+init_x/50, Math.PI*2+init_x/50, true);
```

Change the last variable to false and it should work.

Comment: the problem is still the same

Comment: OK, I solved it now. When drawing the arc, set the value at the end to false. Also, doesn't effect anything but good practise to closePath() when done =)

Answer (score 0):

It is blinking because your computation is wrong.
You need to compute the perimeter: `2*pi*r`.
Then do a simple cross product:

```
distance = x
perimeter = 2*pi
```

So the angle (in radian) is `distance*2*pi/perimeter`

So try this:

```
const getAngle=function(distance) {
    return distance*2*Math.PI/perimeter;
}
const getPos=function(x, y, angle, r) {
    return [x + Math.cos(angle)*r, y + Math.sin(angle)*r];
}
canvas_variable.arc(init_x, init_y, 50, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
canvas_variable.moveTo(..getPos(init_x, init_y, getAngle(init_x-starting_x), r));
canvas_variable.lineTo(init_x, init_y);
canvas_variable.stroke();
```